# How to get list of used UDTF's in SQLRPGLE

Tags: ibm-midrange

I'm trying to get list of UDTF's used in given SQLRPGLE program. I could not find any article/post on getting this kind of information. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not clear why this is closed. It's totally obvious what's being asked, and it's hard to see how the question could be any more specific. Unfortunately, there might be no good answer other than scanning the SQLRPGLE source and somewhat parsing SQL statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was hoping there's be something in `SYSROUTINEDEP`...but that doesn't appear to be the case.

You could try `SYSPROGRAMSTMTSTAT`

```
select * from sysprogramstmtstat
where STATEMENT_TEXT like '%MY_UDTF%';
```

But that's not any better than searching the source code (assuming you have the source).

Also not that the above will only find the static use of your UDTF.  If you're building a dynamic statement that uses the UDTF, it won't be shown.